# Why the getimagesize() function is behaving differently for different parameter[index from $_FILES super-global array] passed?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, superglobals, getimagesize

I've an HTML form with the code to select an image file and upload it to the server.

I also have an incomplete code written in PHP until getting the size of the image that user is uploading to the server.

Please have a look at the code snippets below.

HTML form code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code 1 :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/php_playground/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    echo "Check Value with tmp_name parameter : \n";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($check); 
    echo "</pre>";
    die;
}
?>
```

Output of PHP code 1 is as below :

```
Check Value with tmp_name parameter :

Array
(
    [0] => 1536
    [1] => 2048
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="1536" height="2048"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

PHP code 2 :

```
 <?php
    $target_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/php_playground/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        echo "Check Value with name parameter : \n";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($check); 
        echo "</pre>";
        die;
    }
    ?>
```

Output of PHP code 2 is as below :

**Warning**: getimagesize(demo_image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\uploads\upload.php** on line **8**

Check Value with name parameter :

Now, my query is as I'm trying to upload the same image in both the above programs why I'm getting two different outputs for the `getimagesize()` function for changing the index value from `$_FILES` array?

Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your second code where you are using "name", the function `getimagesize` is not able to read the file.

Here's why:

The "name" variable comes from your browser, hence on the server side the function is unable to locate the image and hence fails to provide information and generate a warning.
While the "tmp_name" is a temporary path of your server side location, where the upload file is temporarily stored. Hence when you use "temp_name" the function is able to read the file and provide you information.

For more information, just print your $_FILES varibale to see the difference between "name" and "tmp_name".

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php